# meta_query with array as value with multiple arrays

Tags: wp-query, customization, meta-query

Already got some clues on how to do this,

see here: [meta_query with array as value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66941/meta-query-with-array-as-value)

but i am confused over multiple meta_queries like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i< count($amenities); $i++)
    {
        $count = count($arrays);
        $arrays[$count] = array(
                    'key' => 'amenities',
                    'value' => $amenities[$i],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    );
    }

for ($j=0; $j< count($amenities2); $j++)
    {
        $count2 = count($arrays2);
        $arrays2[$count2] = array(
                    'key' => 'amenities',
                    'value' => $amenities[$j],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    );
    }
```

then how to include $arrays2 in below query with 'relation' => 'AND'?

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'listing',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'category_name' => 'private_rental',
        'meta_query' => $arrays
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default relation is `AND` so you really don't need to specify that, but I'll show you how to do it anyway.

Really, you just have an array manipulation problem.

```
$amenities = array('a','b','c');
$amenities2 = array('d','e','f');
foreach ($amenities as $a)
{
  $arrays[] = array(
              'key' => 'amenities',
              'value' => $a,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
              );
}

foreach ($amenities2 as $a2)
{
  $arrays2[] = array(
              'key' => 'amenities',
              'value' => $a2,
              'compare' => 'like'
              );
}
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
$meta_query[] = $arrays;
$meta_query[] = $arrays2;
var_dump($meta_query);
```

I also cleaned up your code. It was overly complicated and broken. The `if` statements were overkill for iterating over an array and the `$count = count($arrays);` lines were unnecessary and didn't do anything as you were `count`ing the arrays before they were created. Even if it worked, you had the possibility of clobbering one value with another. If the counts were equal you'd end up overwriting part of the array, not adding to it.

Of course, that is not the only way to put together the final array. In fact, that is probably not the way I'd do it if it were my code. That is probably the easiest way to demonstrate things though.

Comment: Isn't your output an array with two multidimensional arrays inside of it? Shouldn't you use `array_merge` to add $arrays and $arrays2?